# Is there a special name for pi-based finite difference?

Tags: finite-differences

Did anybody consider $\pi$-based finete differences, that is the operator $$\Delta_\pi f(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x)$$ and its corresponding inverse operator? It seems for me that taking the step equal to $\pi$ simplifies many identities much.

For example,

$$\Delta_\pi \sin x = - 2 \sin x$$

$$\Delta_\pi \tan x = 0$$

$$\Delta_\pi^{-1} \sin x = -\frac 12 \sin x + C$$

$$\Delta_\pi^{-1} \cos x = -\frac 12 \cos x + C$$

$$\Delta_\pi^{-1} \tan x = \frac x\pi \tan x + C$$

I want a link to a paper if it is possible, or, at least the term used for such an operator.

Comment: No, I don't believe there's a special name for this (except "finite difference") or that it has been especially studied.

Comment: @nik no, check yourself. Pi is the period of tangent.

Comment: Woops, temporary lapse in judgement.

Comment: The solutions of the inverse operator are wrong. Instead of $C$ it must be $C(x)$ where $C(x)$ is any $\pi$-periodic function, non-continuous included.